# How to delete empty element in popup list

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms

I have a question about a suspicious behaviour in Forms Builder 10.1.2.0.2.

When I have a list object (pop up list) I can define some values in the attribute palette of the object.
So you can set a shown name and a value behind. In this little window to set the items of the popup list you get automatically a white empty item at the end of the list. When I click now on this empty item (you do so, when you want to add an item) Forms Builder automatically adds an new empty item at the end.
When I click this new empty item, Forms Builder adss another empty one ... and so on.
It´s very suspicious because, when I end this dialog with "OK", it will be saved and when I open the form (over web) I have at the end of the list one, two (or more) empty elements in list.
But I can´t delete this empty ones from the list in Forms Builder.

So my question:
how can I delete empty items in a popup list??

I try it with hit "del" button at keyboard or delete the set value for the item (I hope Forms Builder delete items without value). But all does not help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ctrl+shift+<

or

> On my german keyboard it is:
>       ctrl+< for deleting a line
>       ctrl+> (= ctrl+shift+<) for adding a new line

When adding the list elements and list values, make sure you only add the ones you need, if you need 3 elements in your list don't click on the 4th box in the property palette, this will add one more list element.

If you have a blank element and you want to remove it, the only way is to click on the property without clicking the "More..." button press on the "Inherit" button on the top of the property palette, this will reset the list elements and list values so you can add only the elements you want.

if you still have extra empty option then make sure of these:

1- make pop list item required
2- if its database item ... make sure you have yes on databse item and column name filled
3- make the column in table to have default value like '1'

Comment: It worked for me only after the "1- make pop list item required". However, the form builder throws a warningwhen running the form, as follows: "FRM-30188: No initial value given, and other values are not allowed (item ...)". I giess there is no other alternative than ignoring this warning.

Comment: @MazharEhsan dont you have initial property in the form builder you can set, plus it might be related to your plsql do you override it some how, so the question is what do you mean running the form,is it compiling ? or ...

Answer (score 0):

hey perhaps you should try this ctrl+shift+,